# problem in instead of delete views in oracle

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a view as:

```
select * from ot.vw_rebellionrid;
```

which is showing me:

[image]

`full_name` is column of `trainer` table
`subject_name` is column of `subject` table

The view has the query:

```
SELECT full_name, subject_name
     FROM ot.trainer, ot.subject;
```

So,I am learning the instead of delete tigger,so the code for instead of trigger is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ot.io_delete
INSTEAD OF DELETE ON ot.vw_RebellionRid
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM ot.trainer WHERE FULL_NAME = :old.FULL_NAME;
  DELETE FROM ot.subject WHERE SUBJECT_NAME= :old.SUBJECT_NAME;
END;
/
```

So,to execute this trigger,I execute the following statement:

```
delete from ot.vw_RebellionRid where subject_name='java';
```

when it is executed,then :

```
2 rows deleted.
```

According to my understanding,Since the two rows has subject_name as java the remaining output,I think will be after the deletion:

```
--------------------------
full_name | subject_ name |
---------------------------
Manish Sharma Oracle      |
ashwin        Oracle      |
---------------------------
```

But when I executed

```
select * from ot.vw_RebellionRid ;
```

then,I got the output as EMPTY TABLE;

[image]

Since,there were 4rows,2rows were deleted,but when i again select the view then how I am getting empty table?I should have got remaining two rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your trigger is working perfectly.

```
DELETE FROM ot.trainer WHERE FULL_NAME = :old.FULL_NAME;
```

It will delete 2 rows having name `manish` and `ashwin` as both are tagged with `java`.

The same way,

```
DELETE FROM ot.subject WHERE SUBJECT_NAME= :old.SUBJECT_NAME;
```

It will delete subject `java` from table subject so now table `subject` will have 1 record remaining i.e.`Oracle`

Now, your view query will join between 2 tables (`trainer` table with 0 rows and `subject` table with 1 rows) so it is producing no result.

You need to understand that,

```
delete from ot.vw_RebellionRid where subject_name='java';
```

is deleting total 3 records.

Cheers!!

Comment: i am new to this instead of trigger.When the trigger is hitted then if the subject_name='java'; is matched, then BOTH the Delete statement is fired or only the  DELETE FROM subject is fired? I am getting confuse in it

Comment: If you want to know which all records are going to be deleted by the statement: `delete from ot.vw_RebellionRid where subject_name='java';` then execute following select and records which are fetched from this selection will be deleted : `select *  from ot.vw_RebellionRid where subject_name='java';`

Comment: ok thank you so much. This instead of trigger is really used in real case scenario?

Comment: Yes, It is used and it makes the things simple for me (It hides complexity)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when debugging your problem you didn't follow through. Your `INSTEAD OF DELETE` trigger certainly deleted SOMETHING, but to determine *what* was deleted you need to look at the tables underlying the view. If you perform your DELETE statement and then examine the contents of TRAINER and SUBJECT you'll find that the only thing left is the `Oracle` row in SUBJECT. And if you look at your trigger and *think about what you told it to do* you'll realize it did exactly what you told it to do, even if that might not have been what you wanted.

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3ae7ffb6ce1259367042e2b978495af9)

Comment: i am new to this instead of trigger.When the trigger is hitted then if the subject_name='java'; is matched, then BOTH the Delete statement is fired or only the DELETE FROM subject is fired? I am getting confuse in it –

Comment: ***All*** of the code in the trigger is executed, meaning that both the `DELETE FROM TRAINER` and `DELETE FROM SUBJECT` statements are executed.